# "_this.http is undefined" for no reason

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

In my LoginProvider I'm using a function that performs a login and returns the created session as a promise.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginProvider {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { };

    public async login(credentials: ICredentials): Promise<ISession> {

        let url: string = "https:/url/to/login";

        let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()

        let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
            .append("username", credentials.id)
            .append("password", credentials.password);

        return new Promise<ISession>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, params: params }).subscribe((response: ILoginResponse) => {
                // handle response and return session
            }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                reject(error);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that somehow `this.http` is not known when calling it. The following error appears when calling this method.

`"_this.http is undefined"`

And I have no idea why `http` should be undefined in this function. I create it in the constructor and so it should be available for this function, shouldn't it?

Comment: One thing to note, it's @Injectable() <- you're missing the @

Comment: Im guessing that "this" referes to another scope than your LoginProvider. Also, why not use rxjs instead of promises?

Comment: Because I can use `await` on Promises, which I like to use. Or are there alternatives? And yes, I guess there is some problem with scopes here.

Comment: You really should take the advise from Davy and use Observable and not promise. I'd advise watching this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/ (the promise version is shown in the lesson before)

Comment: How are you calling the `login` function?

Comment: How are you importing `HttpClient`?

Answer (score -1):

The `this` inside of the `new Promise` is referring to the new `Promise` object instead of the `LoginProvider` instance.

So, instead of doing

```
new Promise<ISession>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(...)
})
```

you should simple

```
return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, params: params}).toPromise()
  .then(response => // handle your response here then return your processed result);
```

(Don't forget to import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';)

Comment: Good advice to avoid the pointless promise creation, but you're incorrect about `this`. The arrow function binds to the lexical scope